# removing all image metadata using the command line using metaflac

Tags: metadata, flac, id3

If an image/cover art is added to a flac file using

```
metaflac --import-picture-from="/tmp/del/image_jpg.jpg" "/tmp/del/test.flac"
```

I can delete all metadata from a flac file using

```
metaflac --remove-all-tags "/tmp/del/test.flac"
```

But the image remains how can I also delete all cover art?

PS:  I looked here https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-metaflac/

Comment: Did you look at the `--delete` option ? Combined with the description of TYPE in the `--import-picture-from` part, it should be obvious how to delete imported picture.

Answer (score 7):

These two commands should remove the cover art.

```
metaflac --remove --block-type=PICTURE,PADDING --dont-use-padding /tmp/album/*.flac
metaflac --remove-tag=COVERART  --dont-use-padding /tmp/album/*.flac
```

Note that  `--dont-use-padding` tells vorbis not to replace the image data with padding, so the command really is:

1. `--remove`
2. `--block-type` (what to remove, doesn't work as expected unless you also use the next argument)
3. `--dont-use-padding` (tells Vorbis not to replace what was removed with padding)

This was very counter-intuitive, first, why would Vorbis leave padding in place of an image when you remove it? That's some old idea Vorbis group had about keeping the size of the file after a removal the same, roughly. And why would you need to tell it to not replace image data with padding when you are already telling it to remove padding, but that's how it works. I think. For some reason, the remove PADDING item does not appear to do that, unless you use `--dont-use-padding` as well, which seems kind of silly, but that's what my tests showed, I tested pretty heavily and this is what I ended up with that seemed robust and consistent.

This was verified while doing intensive testing on a Vorbis tagging/image embedding feature for some software, during this testing, the FLAC files kept getting bigger and bigger, and I couldn't figure out why, but that's what was going on.

Note that PADDING in Vorbis FLAC files as far as I can tell works roughly the same way Thunderbird email clients have their email 'directory' files, which contain the emails in a single large file. If you delete or move emails from one 'directory' (aka, file), you have to then use the 'Compact Folders' feature to get rid of the space taken up by the moved or deleted emails. FLAC files work roughly the same way as far as I can tell, you can keep adding to the `COMMENT` type items, but it doesn't remove any padding unless you force it to.

Comment: Can you confirm if only other or both of the commands are necessary in order to fully remove the embedded cover images and any padding?

Comment: The post states explicitly what you are asking me to confirm, test it, verify, easy to see with large images just check file size before / after. If you are asking if this is the method I use with success to remove image from metadata, then yes, it is, which is why I posted this.